# sympy solve() result cannot be used in np.isclose(): ufunc 'isfinite' not supported

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

My code is as following. The goal is to, given 1) a circle with radius `r`, 2) a point `(x0, y0)` on it, and 3) a line with `slope` through that point, find out the other point that the line intersects with the circle. To be simple, we assume the line is NOT tangent with the circle.

```py
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

x0, y0 = 1.0, 0.0
slope = 0.0
r = 1.0

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
res = solve([x*x + y*y - r*r, y-y0 - slope*(x-x0)], [x, y])
#if len(res)==1:    # the line NOT tangent with the circle
#   x1, y1 = res[0]
if np.isclose(res[0], [x0, y0]):
   x1, y1 = res[1]
else:
   x1, y1 = res[0]
```

I use `np.isclose()` to exclude the given point `(x0, y0)` from the `solve()` results. However, the code generates an error at line of `np.isclose()` which says:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I debug the code in VScode's DEBUG CONSOLE like following.

```
> res
[(-1, 0), (1, 0)]
> res[0]
(-1, 0)
> np.isclose((-1, 0), [1, 0])
array([False,  True])
> np.isclose(res[0], [1, 0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ufo/miniconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 2358, in isclose
    xfin = isfinite(x)
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Obviously, if `np.isclose()` was given two tuple/list, it is working. But if it was given one result from sympy.solve(), it raises errors.

What should I do with `np.isclose()`?

Comment: what is your expected result for `isclose`? It will return a **array** of `bool`ean values such as `[ True False]` in your case (componentwise comparison). May be need a euclidean distance?

Comment: As a general rule, numpy and sympy don't work together.  `isclose` tests float arrays and has special handling for numpy inf and nan.  Don't expect it to handle sympy symbols or expressions.

Comment: Your `res[0]` looks like a tuple of integers, but what is it exactly?

Comment: second point, the coordinates of the points of the solutions are given as `sympy.core.number.Float` which are not compatible with `numpy`, so do a casting `list(map(float, res[0]))`

Comment: `np.array(res,float)` can turn your solution into a numeric numpy array.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with `np.isclose` here. It is basically just `abs(a - b) < abs(a)*1e-5 + 1e-8)` which is a somewhat arbitrary check in itself not necessarily better than just `abs(a - b) < 1e-14` or something else depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are some compatible issues due to different implementation of "numbers" in the the libraries. `sympy` purposes is to do symbolic computations and will have special functionalities, see the [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.numbers). So, a casting is needed.

Further, to filter the right solution you need to do an extra step, `np.isclose(...).all()`, since you are expecting that both coordinate to be close to each other.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

x0, y0 = 1.0, 0.0
slope = 0.0
r = 1.0

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
res = solve([x*x + y*y - r*r, y-y0 - slope*(x-x0)], [x, y])

if np.isclose(list(map(float, res[0])), [x0, y0]).all():
   x1, y1 = res[1] # carefull that are still sympy.core.numbers.Float!
else:
   x1, y1 = res[0] # carefull that are still sympy.core.numbers.Float!

print(x1, y1)
#-1.00000000000000 0.0
```

---

For a more compact solution, use the the advise of *hpaulj* for the casting:

```
# ...

res = np.array(res, float)

if np.isclose(res[0], [x0, y0]).all():
   x1, y1 = res[1] # as numpy.float64
else:
   x1, y1 = res[0] # as numpy.float64
```